# Thymeleaf timezone

Tags: timezone, thymeleaf

I want to get current time in `GMT+6` but can not make it work. what is the correct format to pass the `timezone`?

I've tried the followings -

```
[[${#dates.createNowForTimeZone('ASIA/DHAKA')}]]

[[${#dates.createNowForTimeZone("ASIA/DHAKA")}]]

[[${#dates.createNowForTimeZone('GMT+6')}]]
[[${#dates.createNowForTimeZone("GMT+6")}]]
```

But, all give the time in `EDT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE November 2022**

Thymeleaf [version 3.1](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf31whatsnew.html) now includes built-in support for `java.time`:

> The `thymeleaf-extras-java8time` extras module has been integrated into the Thymeleaf core: the `#temporals` expression utility object is now always available.

You no longer need to add the extra JAR mentioned below, for Thyeleaf 3.1 onwards.

(Spring Boot 3.0 uses Thymeleaf 3.1, if you are using that.)

---

**Thymeleaf 3.0 and earlier**

I recommend you use the Thymeleaf "extras" library for handling Java 8's `java.time` classes, and avoid anything related to the old and flawed `java.util.Date` class.

The library:

[Thymeleaf - Module for Java 8 Time API compatibility](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time)

If you are using Maven, you can add it to your project using the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise you can download the JARs manually from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-java8time).

---

Once you have installed the new JAR, you can use this:

```
${#temporals.createNowForTimeZone(zoneId)}     // return a instance of java.time.ZonedDateTime
```

For example, as follows:

```
<div th:text="${#temporals.createNowForTimeZone('Asia/Dhaka')}"></div>
```

Or, using the syntax in your question, as follows:

```
[[${#temporals.createNowForTimeZone('Asia/Dhaka')}]]
```

Example output:

```
2022-05-19T18:57:32.190245400+06:00[Asia/Dhaka]
```

That was generated for the target timezone, when my local datetime was `Thu May 19 08:57:32 EDT 2022`.

---

**Note about zone IDs:**

You can read about valid zone IDs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html). In your case, you need to be careful to match the exact case of the ID text - so it has to be `Asia/Dhaka` - not `ASIA/DHAKA`.

See also [Where is the official list of zone names for java.time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42512290/12567365)

---

**Note about formatting**

There is a chance that you are going to want to format the date string, in which case take a look at the various `#temporals.format()` functions listed [here](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time).

But you may also want to consider formatting the string in Java, to keep your Thymeleaf template less cluttered.